# Force ssl on all URLS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have this in my .htaccess file to force ssl

```
#force SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It seems to work for http://example.com/page but not http://example.com/section/page

How do I force ssl on all URLS?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. There was a conflict in my .htaccess file. I moved the force ssl code to the top and it works now.